# Error in Consuming OData from Android using Odata4j?

Tags: android, web-services, odata

Here is my code:

```
 public class callService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
 @Override
 protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try{
         System.out.println("::::::Inside try::::::");
 ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://some:450/HHMSService_Android.svc");
 //GetEmployee?&Mode=1&UserName='DR-OPD'&PWD='DR-OPD'
 System.out.println("C :: "+c);
 List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("GetEmployee?&Mode=1&UserName='DR-OPD'&PWD='DR-OPD'").execute().toList();


 System.out.println("listEntities::::"+listEntities);
 System.out.println("Size"+ listEntities.size());
 if (listEntities.size() > 0) {
 for (OEntity entity : listEntities) {
 categories.add(entity.getProperty("DoctorID").getValue().toString()
 + " - "
 + entity.getProperty("DoctorName").getValue()
 .toString());
 }
 }
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Excepiton::::"+e);
     }
 return categories;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onPostExecute(result);
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
 }
```

I added odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle for consuming Odata. 
I got NullPointerexception on line-

```
 List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("GetEmployee?&Mode=1&UserName='DR-OPD'&PWD='DR-OPD'").execute().toList();
```

Plz help me.My service is giving response in browser.Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can't pass the filtering parameters in getEntities("------") method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put filtering parameters into a different method, like below.

```
List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("GetEmployee")
.filter("-----PASS HERE FILTERING PARAMETERS").execute().toList();
```